# Migrating TFS to another TFS

Tags: azure, tfs, migration

I am using Team Foundation Server by Microsoft. I will probably migrate from one account(server) to another account, and I would like to preserve following things:

- source control of files
- users
- scrum sprints (epics, backlogs, tasks, bugs)
- builds

Azure subscription:

- move all web services
- move all sql databases

How can I approach this? Is this manual work one by one, or can I use some tool for migration?

Comment: Do you want to migrate on-premises TFS or VSTS? If you want to migrate on-premises TFS, do you want [hardware migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware) or [environment migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a TFS migration tool / body of knowledge that will help you thought most of the items you list under TFS. You can find it [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/). This should be fairly straight forward unless you have customised process templates which then create a few more headaches. Moving Builds may be tricky, there is a recently released article on [scripting builds with YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/build-yaml) which may be of use.

For the Azure components, you can:

[Move databases between subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-faq#to-move-a-database-between-subscriptions)

and I believe you can do similar for WebApps/Services. You can also move subscriptions [using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).